# stopping from going in to loop in drools while using insertLogical

Tags: java, drools

I am using insertLogical() in drools.

Here is the rule:

```
rule "logical insert"
salience 100
    when
        $p : Person( $number : number > 1, $name : name == "AB" || name == "AC" )
        not ( exists( PersonConfig( person == $p )))
    then
        System.out.println("Inserted PC");
        insertLogical(new PersonConfig(16,$name,$p));
end

rule "Check Inserted"
salience 90
    when
        $pc : PersonConfig(  )
    then
        System.out.println("Inserted PC Object: "+$pc);
end

rule "Retract Person Config Rule When Clause"
salience 80
    when
        $p : Person( number > 1, name == "AB" || name == "AC"  )
    then
        System.out.println("Retracting : "+$p);
        //$p.setName("BD");
        //retract($p);
        update($p);
end

rule "Checking Person Config Exist"
salience 70
    when
        not ( exists( PersonConfig(  ) ))
    then
        System.out.println("PC not Exists");
end
```

what I am trying to do below:

1. I am selecting all inserted person class object and on the basis of that I am trying to insertLogical (PersonConfig()) object based on some conditon.
2. Now in between I am doing some update on Person class object but the condition on which insertLogical was done remains unchanged. This cause firing of rules "logical insert". Then I tried to put constraints to stop this firing by putting below condition

   not ( exists( PersonConfig( person == $p )))

i.e. If there is no PersonConfig object of attributes having same person reference. but it is not working.

Please check and provide some solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through @PropertyReactive annotation; it is working as per my expectation.It is not reactivating the rule "logical insert" and not going in to loop.

Answer (score 0):

I found one way through @PropertyReactive annotation. By this way, it is working as per my expectation.